# Array of implicitly unwrapped optionals iterates forever in Xcode 8 beta 4

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta4

My code (fragment below) causes the Simulator to Hang.
What am I doing wrong?

To reproduce the problem, cut and paste into the Simulator.

```
class INK
{
    var test = 1
}

var array = [INK!](repeating: nil, count: 1)

for idx in 0..<array.count
{
    array[idx] = INK()
}

var idx2 = 0
for ink_item in array
{
    idx2 += 1
    print("idx2=\(idx2)")
}
```

Comment: You are adding items to the same array you are iterating over.
Your question looks like you have not taken the time to debug it yourself.

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback codingFriend.   The issue that I have is that I want a lazily initiated array.  But the problem that I am facing is that when an array has optional items within it .. the for loop Never exits.  In the above code  array.count =1 ... but the for loop iterates to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, see [SR-1635](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1635). Since an IUO is [no longer a distinct type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md), it shouldn't really be possible to have an array of them in the first place.

This is confirmed by the fact that the following code fails to compile:

```
// compiler error: Implicitly unwrapped optionals are only allowed at top level.
// and as function results
var array: [Ink!] = []
```

<sup>(note I renamed your class name to `Ink` to conform to Swift naming conventions)</sup>

Depending on your situation, you may want to consider using a [`lazy` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255) instead:

```
lazy var array : [Ink] = {

    var array = [Ink]()

    // populate array

    return array
}()
```

Or making the array itself an implicitly unwrapped optional (and defer both the allocation and initialisation of the array):

```
var array : [Ink]!
```

Although note that IUOs should always be a last resort due to their [inherent unsafety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu).

Comment: Thankyou Hamish for link the bug database.  I had tried searches in Apple's bug tracker, but was unsuccessful (and it takes forever to return!).  Thankyou also for the lazy suggestion.  Glad that this is known issue.  I was beginning to think that Swift3 conversion would required me revisiting all for loop to 'break' when 'nil' items were encountered.

Comment: @Antony Actually, I'm still able to reproduce this in Xcode 8 beta 5.

Comment: @ Hamish.  Agreed. This problem is still reproducible on Beta5.