# Swift - Infinite loop for empty array

Tags: swift, loops

I've just upgraded my project to Swift 3 from 2.3. All my for loops are going infinite. I can reproduce it in a fresh playground as well:

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var strs = [String!]()

strs.append("hello")
strs.append("world")

var count = 0
for s in strs {
    count += 1
}
```

What is wrong? In the playground, the loop executes continuously.

Looking at the docs from Apple, this **should** work, shouldn't it?

**UPDATE**:
If I change my array definition as follows, it works as expected. What's the harm in forcing non-optional values in an array?

```
var strs = [String]()
```

**UPDATE 2**:
This is a known bug - https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1635

Comment: Don't know for sure, but generally the way a `for` works is it creates an iterator that will eventually return `nil` when there are no more elements. Using `String!` as the element type may prevent that `nil` from ever being detected.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38849549/2976878 – it's simply a bug. You shouldn't be able to have an array of IUOs, as they are no longer actual types (`var strs: [String!] = []` doesn't compile)

Comment: A workaround may be to use `for i in 0..<strs.count { let s = strs[i]; ... }`.

Comment: An array declared with an implicit unwrapped optional type is nonsense anyway.

Comment: Saw the bug report - I hope somebody fixes it. Thanks Hamish and Kristopher!