# Why does Swift4 cast an array of UIButton! to [UIButton?] type?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I met a strange issue today. Please look at this code:

```
class A {

    var button1: UIButton!
    var button2: UIButton!

    func foo() {
        let array = [button1, button2]
    }
}
```

Xcode says that `array` is `[UIButton?]` type. For some reason Swift4 casts `UIButton!` elements to `UIButton?`. Why?

Comment: Because `button1` and `button2` are optional.

Comment: Is Swift unable to create `[UIButton!]` array?

Comment: Why are you force unwrapping with `!`? Are you trying to create an array of non-optional UIButtons? Typically unwrapping using `!` is only used if the object is nil at the time the class is initialized, but will be definitely initialized later.

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz You cannot have a `[UIButton!]` – as per [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md), `T!` is no longer a distinct type; it's now the same type as `T?` but it allows an attribute to be attached to a declaration (such as a property) allowing it to be force unwrapped in certain circumstances. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/38849549/2976878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39537177/2976878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39633481/2976878 &

Comment: @Stephen Let's assume that `button1` and `button2` are outlets and `foo()` function will customize them.

Comment: Are you sure that your buttons in the array are really optionals? Or is just the type of the array [UIButton?].

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs buttons are optionals. I checked it by using `forEach` method.

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz Ok, it makes sense in the case that these are IBOutlets. Several of the answers below explain well, but I believe vadian's comment above is the correct solution.

Comment: @Stephen I know a solution I looking for explanation. Hamish's answer helps me the most. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EXPLANATION**

`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` is not a distinct type, rather a normal `Optional` with an attribute declaring its value may be implicitly forced (based on [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md)):

> However, the appearance of ! at the end of a property or variable declaration's type no longer indicates that the declaration has IUO type; rather, it indicates that (1) the declaration has optional type, and (2) the declaration has an attribute indicating that its value may be implicitly forced. (No human would ever write or observe this attribute, but we will refer to it as @_autounwrapped.) Such a declaration is referred to henceforth as an IUO declaration.

Thus when you use this:

```
let array = [button1, button2]
```

The compiler derives the `array` type to `[UIButton?]`, because the type of the `button1` and `button2` is `Optional<UIButton>`, not `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIButton>` (even if only one of the buttons was optional, it would derive the optional type).

Read more in [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

**Side note:**

This behavior is not really related to `arrays`, in the following example the type of `button2` will be derived to `UIButton?` even though there is the `!` and there is a value set in `button`:

```
var button: UIButton! = UIButton()

func foo() {
    let button2 = button // button2 will be an optional: UIButton?
}
```

**SOLUTION**

If you want to get an array of unwrapped type, you have two options:

**First**, as [Guy Kogus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627511/guy-kogus) suggested in his answer, use explicit type instead of letting swift derive it:

```
let array: [UIButton] = [button1, button2]
```

However, if per chance one of the buttons contains `nil`, it will cause `Unexpectedly found nil` crash.

While by using implicitly unwrapped optional instead of optional (`!` instead of `?`) you are claiming that there never will be nil in those buttons, I would still prefer the **second** safer option suggested by [EmilioPelaez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725628/emiliopelaez) in his comment. That is to use `flatMap` (`compactMap` in Swift 4+) which will filter out `nil`s, if there are any, and will return an array of unwrapped type:

```
let array = [button1, button2].flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz Glad to help

Comment: Something I would add to this answer is that if you have an array of optionals, you can use `array.flatMap { $0 }` and it will become an array of non-optionals where the `nil` values have been stripped of the array.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thanks for suggestion for improvement, I've elaborated it in the answer

Answer (score 7):

Because `UIButton!` is not a type, or rather it is a `UIButton?` with some conventions. The `!` means always implicitly unwrap the optional. The following

```
 var x: UIButton!
 // Later
 x.label = "foo"
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
 var x: UIButton?
 // Later
 x!.label = "foo"
```

When you create an array of them. The compiler has the choice of implicitly unwrapping them and inferring `[UIButton]` or leaving them as optional and inferring `[UIButton?]`. It goes for the safer of the two options.

Comment: Im not the author of the post, but the last sentence make it clear to me :) Thank you

Comment: I think in the second snippet should be `var x: UIButton?` Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Swift is playing it safe by assuming them to be optionals, rather than unwrapping them by default, since they can technically be `nil`. If you try to explicitly mark them as implicitly-unwrapped like this

```
let array: [UIButton!] = [button1, button2]
```

you will receive the following error:

> error: implicitly unwrapped optionals are only allowed at top level and as function results

In that case, if you want them to be unwrapped then just define it as

```
let array: [UIButton] = [button1, button2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding Swift blog as really the best source for such changes so:

**Before Swift 4:**

> A mental model many people have for implicitly unwrapped optionals is that they are a type, distinct from regular optionals. In Swift 3, that was exactly how they worked: declarations like var a: Int? would result in a having type Optional, and declarations like var b: String! would result in b having type ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.

**Swift 4**

> The new mental model for IUOs is one where you consider ! to be a
>   synonym for ? with the addition that it adds a flag on the declaration
>   letting the compiler know that the declared value can be implicitly
>   unwrapped.
>
> In other words, you can read String! as “this value has the type
>   Optional and also carries information saying that it can be
>   implicitly unwrapped if needed”.
>
> This mental model matches the new implementation. Everywhere you have
>   T!, the compiler now treats it as having type T? , and adds a flag in
>   its internal representation of the declaration to let the type checker
>   know it can implicitly unwrap the value where necessary.

All the quotes taken from [Swift blog](https://swift.org/blog/iuo/)